# How to design database agnostic references in DDD

Tags: database-design, domain-driven-design

While working on separating applications into data domains and make them work independently one cannot avoid references to other domains. While data from another domain should be accessible only via an API I couldn't find an answer on how to properly design a reference between those domains so that they are

- they are api centric
- database agnostic
- not losing database functionalities like grouping

[image]

The image should visualize the intend, though what is the right approach here?

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

When multiple systems have to interact with each other, I'd recommend using [GUIDs](http://guid.us/) to store references between them.

As per its description, GUIDs are used to globally uniquely identify something, regardless of what it is and where it's stored. If you have multiple systems storing data in different places, and you'd need to merge/group them and ensure their uniqueness, use GUIDs. They are:

- Unique across tables, databases, servers, so you can safely
  *join/merge* data which you stored in different places
- Predictable, no need to insert in table to generate it
- No need of Central Authority, if multiple systems are registering
  orders, for example, and need to share with them, there is no need to
  have a central place to control whether they duplicates
- People/Evil Robots can't just call a GET method in an API *guessing*
  IDs, which improves security

You can read more [here](https://betterexplained.com/articles/the-quick-guide-to-guids/).